# Can I match a multiline pattern with sed

Tags: linux, sed

Suppose I have this pattern in a file:

```
<directory number=133 name=var1> 
<myfile name=test1 /> 
</directory>
```

Now I want to replace that pattern with

```
<directory number=133 myfile=test1 />
```

How can I do that with `sed`?

Comment: Which parts of the patterns above are variable and which are fixed?  At a guess, the value for `number` and the value for `name` in the `<myfile>` tag are variable and need to be copied.  If it is all fixed, then it is much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed is not good for multi-line stuff, however:

```
sed ':l;N;$!tl;N;s!<directory number=133 name=var1>[ ]*\n<myfile name=test1 />[ ]*\n</directory>!<directory numbe=133 myfile=test1 />!' input
```

This command first reads all of the file in a loop:

```
:l;N;$!tl;N;  # label l, read line, while not eof jump to label l
```

Where `:l` is the label. `N` is the read next line and append it to the buffer command. `$!` tests if not (`!`) end of file (`$`). `t` is the branch if last test successful command. `t` is followed by the label name to branch to, hence `tl`. The last `N` append the last line to the buffer before proceeding.

then basically matches the input in the question and replaces it with the desired output using the substitute (`s!regex!replace!`) command.

If you also want to capture all different numbers and names:

```
sed ':l;N;$!tl;N;s!<directory number=\([0-9]*\) name=\([^>]*\)>[ ]*\n<myfile name=test1 />[ ]*\n</directory>!<directory number=\1 myfile=\2 />!' input
```

Comment: can you please tell me what happenning there

Comment: i still not understood this `:l;N;$!tl;N;` cab you put them in separate and line explain what is the use of each . i mean `N` , $, !, tl , N

Comment: Can you give me link/tutorial  form internet where i can see these variable name. i finisged CBT sed training and haven't learn any of those variables there

Comment: @pereal why did you use `!` instead of `/` in `s!regex!replace!` i want to add the `/g` flag and i am not bale to

Comment: you can use the `g` flag. I used `!` because the regex contains `/` and I did not want to escape it. You can use `g` as in `!regex!replace!g`

Comment: @pereal where did u write in the code that you are chaging `/` to `;` or system automatically detects it

Comment: the character following the `s` command is the delimiter. there is no default substitution delimiter in sed.

Comment: thanks dude, u don't know how many SO questions and comments i needed to clar that